# Setting scoreboard score based on player location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If a player is standing at this location, I want their score to be set to 1 on objective inSpawn. Help.

Comment: This time it was answered, next time please do at least a little bit of research yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses 2 command blocks in a chain.  The first command block resets the score for all players.  The second command block sets the score to 1 for all players within a specified radius from the specified coordinates.  Minecraft Java Edition version is currently 1.12.2.

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players reset @a inSpawn
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players set @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R] inSpawn 1
```

Replace X, Y, and Z with the [coordinates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_coordinate).  Replace R with the desired [radius](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_radius).  The radius will determine how large of an area it will accept players.  You can instead use [volume arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_volume) in the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) if you want to specify the area.

Comment: Using the `<key>` tag for the command block GUI buttons, good idea!

Comment: @Fabian The tag used was `<kbd></kbd>`.  I figured they represent user input as buttons and it makes it stand out in the answer.  I found the page on [allowed HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909) a while back. I experimented with several of the tags in the hopes of improving my answer formatting and clarity.